# JavaScript variable remains undefined

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with my webpage. The JavaScript isn't doing what it should because a variable[] isn't being populated! Please consider my code:

```
var datasets = { "DataItem1": {
label: "Idle Count",
dataSeries: [[13, 75.72],[13, 1],[13, 0.17],[13, 55.72],[13, 90.72],[13, 91.06]],
Threshold_0: [[134, 1],[133, 1]],
Threshold_2: [[133, 1],[131, 1]]
}
};

var data = [];
var failedData = [];

data.push(datasets['DataItem1']['dataSeries']);
failedData.push(datasets['DataItem1']['Threshold_0']['Threshold_2']);

});
```

The issue is with

```
failedData.push(datasets['DataItem1']['Threshold_0']['Threshold_2']);
```

Using firebug's watch window, I can see that failedData is undefined when I add a break at this point. So, I hover the mouse over the array items on this line, and Threshold_0 has data, but Threshold_2 does not (Threshold_2 is undefined).

In the watch window, I can see that datasets[] has created all the objects as expected.

I can't see why and I'm very stuck.

Comment: Try putting your Threshold_X between single quotes, as to have them being named properties.

Comment: cuz `datasets['DataItem1']['Threshold_0']['Threshold_2']` is `undefined`.I think you are looking for `datasets['DataItem1']['Threshold_2']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are trying to access the property `Threshold_2` through `Threshold_0`, you should get it through `DataItem1`

```
failedData.push(datasets['DataItem1']['Threshold_0']['Threshold_2']);
```

**Becomes**

```
failedData.push(datasets['DataItem1']['Threshold_2']);
```

Comment: Yes, I see now. So, my final code is `failedData.push(datasets['DataItem1']['Threshold_0'], datasets['DataItem1']['Threshold_2']);` which works great

Answer (score 1):

The following properties *do* have a value:

```
datasets['DataItem1']['Threshold_0'][0] == [134, 1]
datasets['DataItem1']['Threshold_0'][1] == [133, 1]
```

I'm not sure what you actually want to do. Maybe this is what you intend to do?

```
failedData.push(datasets['DataItem1']['Threshold_0']);
failedData.push(datasets['DataItem1']['Threshold_2']);
```

Otherwise, please describe what value(s) you want to end up in `failedData`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo at the end. Remove the last });